# Can use FToC to evaluate $\lim _{x\to \infty }\frac{\int _0^x\:f\left(t\right)dt}{x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

We have $f\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=\cos(x)-1+\frac{x^2}{2}$. We have to evaluate $$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty }\frac{\int\limits_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt}{x^2}$$.

Here is my solution: $$\int\limits_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt=\frac{6\cdot \sin\left(x\right)-6x+x^3}{6}$$

So we'll have:
$$\frac{\int\limits_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt}{x^2}=\frac{6\cdot \sin(x)-6x+x^3}{6x^2}=\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{x}{6} \rightarrow \infty $$ and is divergent.

We can solve it with FToC?

Comment: You don't need to integrate, just prove that the integral diverges and use L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: can you show your solution ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because $f(x)\ge \frac{1}{2}x^2-2$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$.  Hence the limit is of the indeterminate form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ and we apply L'Hopital's rule.  We find the derivative of the numerator by the FTC, getting
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^xf(t)dt}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{2x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\cos x}{2x}-\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{x}{4}$$

These three limits evaluate to $0$ (by the squeeze theorem), $0$, and $+\infty$, respectively; hence their sum has limit $+\infty$.

Comment: so my solution is not good?

Comment: Your solution is fine, but you asked to use the FTC.